# How does tell() method displaying output as 11 instead of 10?

Tags: python, file-handling

Content of raj.txt:

```
one line
two line
three line
four line
five line
six line
seven line
eight line
nine line
ten line
```

Code:

```
with open('raj.txt', 'r') as f:
    size = 10
    f_contents = f.read(size)
    print(f_contents,end='*')
    print(f.tell())
    f_contents = f.read(size)
    print(f_contents, end='*')
    print(f.tell())
```

Output:

```
    one line
    t*11
    wo line
    th*22
```

Comment: You probably have CRLF newlines, which is 2 characters.

Comment: @Barmar , Thanks.  if CRLF is the case, then print(f_contents) should have displayed in output as 'one line' instead of 'one line \n t' right? please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Because of Python's [universal newline](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) handling, it's possible for the actual file position to differ from the number of characters that have been read — which is why `tell()` often isn't useful when reading text files, at least on some OSs.

Comment: Open the file in binary mode and you'll get the CR and LF as separate bytes. When you open in text mode, it converts the CRLF to newline. @RajChiranjeevi